# Deleting Rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to delete some rows in an excel file based on if the cells are empty.
There are 2 cells that can contain some user data
and if either one of those cells has the data, I need to keep it, otherwise, if both cells are empty, delete the row.

I figured out how to delete rows based on if 1 cell is empty.
I want it to look at column 6 and column 8,
if both are empty, delete the row.
If only one of them is empty, keep the row.

current code is this

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('Pull-1.xlsx')
sheetlist = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetlist[0])



rownumber = 1
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row= sheet.max_row, min_col=8, max_col=8, values_only=True):
  rownumber += 1
for i in range(sheet.max_row, 1, -1):
        if sheet.cell(row=i, column=8).value is None:
            sheet.delete_rows(i, 1)



wb.save('pull-1mod.xlsx')
```

Also... If I have something extra that is not needed, please let me know.
I'm just learning, and pieced this together from researching on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change if-statement to:

`if sheet.cell(row=i, column=8).value is None and sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value is None:`